# set new list variable equal to list generated in a function that has listbox values passed to it

Tags: python, function, listbox, tkinter

I have created a function that should take the user selections in a listbox, and populate a list them. I then want to be able to access this list outside of the function, but i'm not sure how to do it. I know I should call the function but I'm confused as to how to pass anything to it.. here is my code

```
def usr_fc(*events):
   UsrFCList = []
   selctd_indices = lbox.curselection()
   lst_select = list(selctd_indices)
   for i in lst_select:
     UsrFCList.append(lbox.get(i))
   lbox.quit()
```

I have edited this to include all of the code i have so far:

```
#import modules and functions
import arcpy
import tkFont
from Tkinter import *

#create entry widget and get/set variable/workspace with function 'set_wkspc'
def set_wkspc():
  wk = e_ws.get()
  arcpy.env.workspace = wk
  e_ws.quit()

wk_input = Tk()

e_ws = Entry(wk_input, width=75)
e_ws.pack()

e_ws.focus_set()

b = Button(wk_input, text="choose workspace", width=15, command=set_wkspc)
b.pack()

mainloop()

#function to list all feature classes within specified workspace
def getFC(ws):
  ws = arcpy.env.workspace
  FCList1 = []
  FCList2 = []
  fcs1 = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
  FCList1.append(fcs1)
  fds = arcpy.ListDatasets()
  for fd in fds:
    arcpy.env.workspace = ws + '/'  + fd
    fcs2 = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
    FCList2.append(fcs2)
  FCList1.extend(FCList2)
  return FCList1

x = arcpy.env.workspace

lb_list = getFC(x)

#new Listbox class and function that sets up a listbox size according to its contents
class AutoSzLB(Listbox):
def autowidth(self,maxwidth):
    f = tkFont.Font(font=self.cget("font"))
    pixels = 0
    for item in self.get(0, "end"):
        pixels = max(pixels, f.measure(item))
    # bump listbox size until all entries fit
    pixels = pixels + 10
    width = int(self.cget("width"))
    for w in range(0, maxwidth+1, 5):
        if self.winfo_reqwidth() >= pixels:
            break
        self.config(width=width+w)

#list variable for user's choice of feature classes and a function that creates
#list of chosen feature classes

def usr_fc(*events):
  UsrFCList = []
  selctd_indices = lbox.curselection()
  lst_select = list(selctd_indices)
  for i in lst_select:
    UsrFCList.append(lbox.get(i))
  lbox.quit()

#generate scrollbar, execute button and listbox of feature classes to select
#for analysis
fc_lb = Tk()
scrollbar = Scrollbar(fc_lb)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
lbox = AutoSzLB(fc_lb,selectmode=EXTENDED)
for item in lb_list:
  lbox.insert(END, *item)

button = Button(fc_lb, text="Analyze selected feature classes", command=usr_fc)

lbox.autowidth(250)
lbox.pack()
button.pack()

#attach listbox to scrollbar
lbox.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.config(command=lbox.yview)

mainloop()

#create entry widget and set workspace for analysis output
def set_out_wkspc():
  wk = out_ws.get()
  ident_ouput_path = wk
  out_ws.quit()

out_wk = Tk()

out_ws = Entry(out_wk, width=75)
out_ws.pack()

out_ws.focus_set()

b2 = Button(out_wk, text="set output workspace", width=20, command=set_wkspc)
b2.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: Try returning the list from the function, or (not recommended) assigning it to a global variable.

Comment: I think you need to show us more context for this code.  It looks like `usr_fc` is a callback function for an event, in which case you need to wrap the callback function to allow it access to your GUI object's namespace, but it's hard to advise you without more context, because it depends a lot on how the rest of the GUI is coded.

Comment: Is there a reason you're intentionally creating and then destroying the first root window? That's highly unusual. A GUI typically creates a window that lives until the program exits.

Comment: im very new with this, all i want is for the window to close when a value has been given or chosen.. i assumed i needed to quit or destroy to close it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the quick fix:

```
UsrFCList = []  # You've added this name to the module-level namespace.

def usr_fc(*events):
   selctd_indices = lbox.curselection()
   lst_select = list(selctd_indices)
   for i in lst_select:
     UsrFCList.append(lbox.get(i))  # The interpreter looks for UsrFCList in the local function namespace, and since you're not assigning to that name, it look at the next biggest namespace, which is the module namespace.
   lbox.quit()

# You should now have access to any data you put in UsrFCList, outside the usr_fc function.
```

However, the best way to handle this problem is to rewrite your code so your GUI's internal data, widgets, and callback functions are housed within their own class.  That way they can all share a class namespace, so they can communicate data to each other like the contents of `UsrFCList`.  In the long run, if you want to make GUIs of any complexity, you're going to want to do something like what I've outlined below.

Without rewriting your whole code, it would roughly look like this:

```
class App:
    def __init__(root, self):
        # initialize your class with all your widgets
        self.fc_lb = root
        self.button = Button(fc_lb, text="Analyze selected feature classes", command=lambda *events:self.usr_fc(*events))
# Note  ^^^^ all your widgets and data will be accessible through the `self` reference to your GUI instance.
        self.UsrFCList = []
        self.lbox = AutoSzLB(self.fc_lb,selectmode=EXTENDED)
        # . . . you'd have to add all the other setup required to make your GUI

    def usr_fc(self, *events):
    #          ^^^^ you now have access to everything in the instance namespace available inside usr_fc 
        self.UsrFCList = []
        selctd_indices = lbox.curselection()
        lst_select = list(selctd_indices)
        for i in lst_select:
            self.UsrFCList.append(lbox.get(i))
        self.lbox.quit()

    # . . . and you'd add all the other functions that need to work with internal GUI widgets/data 

rootWindow = Tk()
newGUI = App(rootWindow)  # Create a new GUI instance
rootWindow.mainloop()

# Hopefully that gives you the idea.
```